# importing data skipping first id column

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench, workbench

I am creating my first database using workbench, but I have a problem with the import of the data into the relational table. It consists of `name_id`, `name`, `surname`.

I've marked AI for the `name_id` to set the value automatically, 
but when I want to import the .csv data it inserts into the two first columns - `name_id` and `name` instead of into `name` and `surname`.

How can I import data directly to the column `name` and `surname` skipping the first column (`name_id`) of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mysql shell console, and then use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) there.

In order to use that, and to auto-increment your ID column, you need to have NULL as the first column value.

So first prepare your file:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*?;/\\N;/' data.csv > data_processed.csv
```

Command above replaces all ID's in your file with '\N' which is a symbol for null.

Then just import this file into your database.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "data_processed.csv" INTO TABLE name;
```

Comment: I've already have the processed data, but the tool 'import records from an external file' in workbench is inserting it still in the 1st and 2nd column. I would like to insert the data in the 2nd and 3rd column skipping the 1st one, in other words, leaving the 1st column blank. I am not sure if it is possible, because this is my very first experience with workbench, though, I haven't found the solution for this problem.

Comment: Hi, I've corrected my answer. Is using 'mysql' tools an option in your case?

Comment: I am creating a database which will be connected to netbeans, so I guess I can use also terminal, workbench is just better visualized

Comment: just to explain what I wanted, maybe someone will use it:

LOAD DATA INFILE "path/data.csv" 
INTO TABLE table_name
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(first_name, surname); - this part is what I've needed - it specifies the columns to which I wanted to import the data skipping the id_name column.

Comment: Hi @Kashtan,
`LOAD DATA INFILE "path/data.csv" INTO TABLE table_name fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (first_name, surname)`
Is this the right syntax?
Coz' its not working for me.